# "#markup" form element can't have children

Tags: 7, forms

I have my form, but any child of the "#markup" element will not appear when the form is being rendered.

```
$form['html'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => '<h2>My Heading</h2>',
  '#tree' => true,
);

$form['html']['element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Foo',
);
```

In this example the "element" form field will not be rendered.

Is this a Drupal bug, or do I need to do something specific?

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a misconception. One cannot inject other elements in a markup text. Instead create a container and add the markup and the textfield there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not being able to use "#tree" with a "#markup" element seems a bug of Drupal, as [the reference page for the form API reports that "#tree" is supported by the "#markup" element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#markup).

As workaround, you can also use the "#prefix" property, as in the following code:

```
$form['html']['element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Foo',
  '#prefix' => '<h2>My Heading</h2>',
);
```

If it is not rendered as you expect, then you can simply remove "#tree" from your code, which doesn't seem to be needed, if all you want is to render the `<h2>My Heading</h2>` tag before the form fields. The form API renders the elements following the order they appear in the array; if you want to alter the order, you can use the "[#weight](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#weightval)" property.

```
$form['html'] = array(
 '#type' => 'markup',
 '#markup' => '<h2>My Heading</h2>',
);

$form['html']['element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Foo',
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do need the tree element as my actual form is a little more sophisticated than the above example. I'm also trying to avoid using prefix/suffix markup values in order to keep to code cleaner and such.  My form consists of a few loops generating a tree structure of elements with a depth of about 4.  If the 'markup' element type can't have children than I'll have to restructure some of my form.

Comment: It seems a bug of Drupal, as the "markup" element is supposed to be able to use "#tree"; what I reported are the only workarounds/alternatives I know of.

Comment: I opened a issue report: http://drupal.org/node/1261040. The referring version is 8.x because the bugs are first fixed in Drupal 8, and then back ported to the previous versions.